# regular expressions in Apache: end with any combination of sthg

Tags: regex, apache

I am trying to represent the fact of that a string ends with any combination of the characters `.`, `-`, or `_`.

I have tried with:

```
([.-_]+)
```

But I do not get what I want.
Any idea?

Comment: you may be looking for `^.*([\.-_]+)$`

Comment: I am afraid that does not work. Anybody knows how $ works? It seems that it works a bit strange. a$ refers to any string ending in a but when I try with something more complicated it does not work as I suspect.

Comment: The point is that I need to get a substring which ends on any combination of ., - or _. Any idea? thank you very much

Comment: Can you add on your question a set of valid and invalid examples please?

Comment: and I would like to obtain: C.yutg

Comment: I will delete my answer since it doesn't attend your requirements. You should update your question with more examples. One information that is important and you have missed: the text may also have `.` inside before the end.

Comment: You should edit your question with input and expected output.